# Is there a guideline for Unix config files

Tags: linux, unix, dotfiles, configuration-files

Most config files are ini files (format: name=value\n). Is there any documentation or an article/guideline on this matter.

Or is anyone supposed to keep close to this format on good will?

Comment: There are a lot of libraries (or existing functions) that you can reuse to read and parse those files. But feel free to invent your own format or use XML...

Comment: From FreeBSD Handbook: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/kernelconfig-config.html And Linux Kernel: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/sag-configuration-file.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately, UNIX is hardly decided on this issue. There are [too many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file#UNIX.2FLinux) formats. With session managers like Gnome, some apps have moved out from maintaining config files to keeping stuff in the Gnome registry (gconf).

Here are some general observations.

The `ini` format you alluded to is fairly widespread. It does have the problem that you'd have to do some tricks to assign a list of values etc. but for most situations, it's fine, well supported and widely available.

Most formats used in UNIX rely on the `#` character as commenting the rest of the line. If you are rolling out something by yourself, it would be good to stick to this.

`YAML` is a human readable lightweight format that you can use (and many apps do use it though not as much as I'd like).

There's a convention that all system level config files are kept in `/etc` and user level ones are kept as file starting with `.` in the users home directory (dot files).

Some applications (notably `Emacs`) keeps a runnable program in a full fledged programming language as it's config file. This might be unsafe in an untrusted environment but very powerful and useful in a trusted one.

For a new project, I'd go with `ini` as a `.programrc` in the home directory.

There's a useful section in the [art of unix programming](https://web.archive.org/web/20191026064400/www.faqs.org/docs/artu/configurationchapter.html) about configuration formats and files that might be worth your while to check out.

Comment: A good starting point/litmus test would be to see the formats that already have a lens in http://augeas.net/

Comment: With Eric S. Raymond's articles on rc files linked below in mind I guess there is nothing more to say. Thanks.

Comment: Also, please consider following the current trend of having the per-user config file(s) under ~/.config/appname rather than directly under the user home dir, helping reduce home dir clutter. E.g. on my home dir @work, I seem to have 242 dotfiles/dirs.. :(